# "filter" или "inline svg" для background-image?

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-filter, css-filters

Считается ли костылем использовать свойства `filter` для `background-image` вместо `inline svg`
для смены цвета вместо

```
 fill: #ffa500
```

использовать

```
filter: invert(65%) sepia(54%) saturate(2331%) hue-rotate(359deg) 
brightness(102%) contrast(106%);
```

Comment: А что такое костыль? А одного `hue-rotate` не достаточно для смены цвета?

Comment: @elka Что-то не так с ответом? Остались вопросы?

Answer (score 1):

Конечно добавление инлайн (копирование) SVG в HTML является самым простым и надежным способом для последующей стилизации изображения.

Но и другие способы добавления SVG, например с помощью `<img>`, `background-image`
с последующей стилизацией с помощью SVG или CSS фильтров ***являются вполне валидными***.

Мало того, других приемов окрасить изображение, кроме как фильтрами, при таких способах добавления, просто нет.

Вот например изображение добавлено с помощью `<img>` и при наведении на иконку срабатывают CSS фильтры и перекрашивают иконку

```css
img {
width:60px;
height:60px;
}
img:hover {
filter: invert(65%) sepia(54%) saturate(2331%) hue-rotate(359deg) 
brightness(102%) contrast(106%);
transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://svg-art.ru/files/menubutton.svg" />
```

Следующий пример при добавлении изображения background

```css
.box {
width:60px;
height:60px;
background:url(https://svg-art.ru/files/menubutton.svg);
transition: all 0.5s;
}
.box:hover {
filter: invert(65%) sepia(54%) saturate(2331%) hue-rotate(359deg) 
brightness(102%) contrast(106%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Даже когда изображение в формате ***base64*** добавлено инлайн, его можно покрасить только фильтрами.

Ниже пример с работой SVG фильтров

Наведите на здание курсор:

```css
.R1:hover {
filter:url(#RedFilter);
} 

.G1:hover {
filter:url(#GreenFilter);
}
.B1:hover {
filter:url(#BlueFilter);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="150" viewBox="0 -30 400 150" style="border:1px solid grey;"> 

  <defs>
 <filter id="RedFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="150" height="150">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter> 
    <filter id="GreenFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="140" height="140">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter> 
    
    <filter id="BlueFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="140" height="140">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter> 
    
    <filter id="WhiteFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="140" height="140">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter>
 


   <image id="Building" width="100" height="100"  xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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"/>   
   </defs> 
    
   <use class="R1" id="BuildingRed" xlink:href="#Building" x="20" y="0"   ></use> 
   <use class="G1" id="BuildingGreen" xlink:href="#Building" x="150" y="0"  ></use> 
    <use class="B1" id="BuildingBlue" xlink:href="#Building" x="280" y="0"  ></use>
   
   
</svg>
```

Comment: Так я не понял, а костылем то считается?))

Comment: @Leonid цитата из ответа: "стилизацией с помощью SVG или CSS фильтров являются вполне валидными."

Comment: Поэтому я и спросил у автора что она считает костылем. Потому что в моем понимании "костыль" - это окольный путь для достижения желаемого результата, часто использующий неявные методы, побочные эффекты языка. Это валидные, допустимые способы с точки зрения синтаксиса, но уродливые с точки зрения понимания и чистого кода. А в данном случае, скорее, речь должна идти еще и о быстродействии и эффективности. Как-то так... но хорошо бы услышать автора))

Comment: @Leonid других способов, кроме как с помощью фильтров, стилизовать изображение, добавленное через background, img, в CSS и SVG нет. Так что о красоте кода и производительности говорить не приходится. Применяемые фильтры здесь быстро работают, так как нет анимации и размытия.

Comment: Способов перекрасить изображение нет, но есть другие способы менять цвет картинке, в том числе и с помощью inline SVG, canvas и прочего. Об этом речь, есть заменители, и ими можно пользоваться. И это будет явно, прямолинейно и читабельно.

Comment: @Leonid ты не обратил внимание на последний пример? Там изображение добавлено инлайн, но оно формата base64, поэтому его можно покрасить только с помощью фильтров. Я совсем не знаю canvas, но если возможно перекрасить, как-то по другому, то наверное код будет не сильно короче. Я имею ввиду именно крайний пример

Comment: Фишка всех языков вэба в том (включая SVG), что они читаются людьми. Это было сделано в ущерб производительности и прочему, но это безопасность и открытость. И если нельзя явно понять намерения разработчика выражением в фильтрах, то и нечего писать такое. Вот так все просто, по-моему.

Comment: @Leonid Ты к чему призываешь? Отказаться от матриц в записи фильтров? Так вот в таком виде, а не в одну строчку, как раз и понятно и наглядно, где поставить в фильтре `feColorMatrix`  единичку, чтобы был тот или иной цвет

Comment: `filter: invert(65%) sepia(54%) saturate(2331%) hue-rotate(359deg) 
brightness(102%) contrast(106%)` - я вот про такой вид вместо `fill: green`, например. Что более наглядно?

Comment: @Leonid я думаю и тебе уже надоело спорить ни о чём. На крайнем примере я показал применяемость svg фильтров Они намного мощнее, чем CSS фильтры, который являются их урезанной копией. Тебе хотелось поспорить? Что ж я доставил тебе такое удовольствие.

Comment: Я пока ни о чем не спорю, я просто говорю, что вопрос автора в том, насколько правильно использовать `filter...` против `fill...`. А не в том, как еще можно поменять цвет изображению. Вот я и говорю, что чем яснее для читающего код, тем лучше. Вот и все. Ты это не оспаривал и я твои слова тоже не оспаривал. Спора не вижу.

Comment: @Leonid  А я говорю, что в ситуациях, когда невозможно применять `fill=""` придется применять `filter=""`

Comment: Я так понял, что у автора есть возможность использовать оба метода, но она считает, что inline-SVG сильно засоряет код страницы. Поэтому рассматривает альтернативы, но это ее мнение нужно. Я понял твою мысль, и ее не оспариваю. Ни к чему не призываю, просто уточнял свою мысль и свой взгляд на эти вещи. Чем яснее намерения разработчика кода - тем лучше.